# Unexpected behaviour of window.innerwidth

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

```
if(window.innerWidth) {
    return window.innerWidth;
}
return $(window).width();
```

I am using the above code to find the available width of a web page. It works most of the time. But in some mobile browsers (Mobile Chrome and a few) and sometimes in desktop website it returns 0. I don't know, what went wrong?

**Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-J500M Build/LMY48B) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36**

This is one of the user agent where it is failed.  Mostly it happen in mobile chrome in android browser.

Comment: When is this code running? Is the page fully loaded when it tries to get the page width?

Comment: I've seen this behavior when a tablet or mobile device is playing it's "orientation change animation" (for want of a better term). If you are listening to onresize events on the document, and the transition between portrait to landscape occurs, reading viewport size sometimes results in 0 whilst the transition animation is playing. I can only imagine this is a result of rendering optimizations inside the browser.

Answer (score 5):

You might try forcing the test in the `if` to be a Boolean.

```
if(!!window.innerWidth) {
  return window.innerWidth;
}
return $(window).width();
```

Having more than on `return` statement in a function is not always considered best practice. You can make this clearer as follows.

```
return !!window.innerWidth ?
   window.innerWidth :
   $(window).width();
```

If this doesn't work then the issue is that you have found a bug in jQuery's width method.

Comment: funny way of forcing a boolean check haha. I think in this case u can even write `return window.innerWidth || $(window).width();` since if window.innerWidth returns 0 or undefined we still want to try the jQuery method.